# Could not load file or assembly System

Tags: asp.net, iis, iis-7, windows-server-2008

We have a customer that is using Server 2008 x86 II7 with asp.net 3.5SP1. When our asp.net application is installed we are getting the following error:

Could not load file or assembly 'System, Version=2.0.50727'

Has anyone ran into this issue? Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Check your applications web.config - are you binding to that version for some reason by any chance?
Its possible it is referencing the wrong version. The assembly version is 2.0.0.0 but the *file* version is 2.0.50727.  Once you open up the gac, right click on the System library for 2.0.0.0 and look at the file version there. What are the results? If its missing, Install asp.net 2 (asp.net 3.5 were files included on top of v2 assemblies - for asp.net it did not replace them)